# How to resolve 'Missing argument for parameter 'realmManager' in call' error for TasksView() in Realm?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, realm, realm-mobile-platform

Getting an error of "Missing argument for parameter 'realmManager' in call" for TasksView()

I tried to read the documentations for Realm but based on the code, I don't think there is anything wrong? There is something missing but I don't know what it is.

Code is below:

TasksView File -

```
import SwiftUI

struct TasksView: View {
    @Environment var realmManager: RealmManager
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Task List")
                .font(.title3).bold()
                .padding()
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            
            
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(Color(hue: 0.086, saturation: 0.141, brightness: 0.901))
    }
}

struct TasksView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TasksView()
            .environmentObject(realmManager)
        
          
    }
}
```

ContentView2 File -

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView2: View {
    @StateObject var realmManager = RealmManager()
    @State private var showAddTaskView = false
    
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottomTrailing){
            TasksView()
                .environmentObject(realmManager)
            
            SmallAddButton()
                .padding()
                .onTapGesture {
                    showAddTaskView.toggle()
                }
            
            
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showAddTaskView) {
            AddTaskView()
                .environmentObject(realmManager)

            
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottom)
        .background(Color(hue: 0.086, saturation: 0.141, brightness: 0.901))
    }
}

struct ContentView2_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView2()
    }
}
```

Comment: bro you are right

Comment: lol this is so embarrassing

Answer (score 2):

`@Environment` works with the [`environment`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/environment(_:_:)) view modifier, and allows you to read a value of a particular key path of [`EnvironmentValues`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues).

You are using `environmentObject` to inject the realm manager, since you want to share the realm manager among the views. You should use [`@EnvironmentObject`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentobject) to read the values from `environmentObject` modifiers, not `@Environment`.

Declare `realmManager` like this:

```
@EnvironmentObject var realmManager: RealmManager
```